# Many Facebook 'Like' buttons on one page with different thumbnails

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I need to have two different `Like` buttons on one web-page.

First one - to like some article/photo (thumbnail is set via og:image meta-tag)
Second one - to like my page.

But how can I set right thumbnail for second `Like` button?
Is it possible to set thumbnail-url in `<fb:like>` tag?

For example this url http://kuvaklubi.fi/photo/411/golden-tunnel/ (not adv, but demo).
On right sidebar I have `Like` button to like photo. All needed open-graph tags are set to this photo. But on footer I have another `Like` button. And I'd like set own image, that appears on Facebook's wall. But how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume there's two URLs.  One for the page and one for the image.

Run each of those two URLs thru Facebook's linter: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint
From your example page:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fkuvaklubi.fi%2F

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fkuvaklubi.fi%2Fphoto%2F411%2Fgolden-tunnel%2F

You will see what it recommends (if anything) to fix in your og: tags.

To specify the image, set the url in the og:image meta tag.
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://kuvaklubi.fi/img/kk.jpg" />`
vs
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://kk-static.fi/photos/2/3/f/5/8/wall/23f588dc1582b4ca251a146148a964149d15b434.jpg" />`

Comment: Yes, I tried to `lint` this page with no luck :)
I have one `url` with two different `like` buttons. Each button have own `url`. First - photo url, and second - whole page url. Of course, I can set two different `<og:image>` tags on each page, but then user has to choice, which one to use.

Comment: Take a closer look at your example page you sent.  It only has one og:image tag on each of those two pages.  Even though the like is on one page, each like button represents a different URL. It's what the URL lints to that is important.