# Re-rendering Facebook plugins using FB.XFBML.parse

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk, xfbml

Is there a way to use FB.XFBML.parse without rendering the a Facebook plugin again which cause it to "flicker" (disappear et reappear).

Will be using the Facebook Like button or Facebook Recommandations Bar.

Live example: http://www.gablabelle.com/eve-d

Slide to view the flickering in the lower right corner.

```
$.address.state(ajax_object.path).crawlable(true).value(whereiam);
$(".fb-recommendations-bar").data("href",whereiamurl);
//$(".fb-like").data("href",whereiamurl);
fburl = $(".fb-recommendations-bar").data("href");
//fburl = $(".fb-like").data("href");
console.log(fburl);
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the scope of the re-parse by passing in the parent DOM element to `FB.XFBML.parse`.

Comment: Yes but it still renders the Facebook plugin again.

Comment: What you ask for doesn't make sense then - how can you possibly load the the plugin again (new data) without actually reloading it?

Comment: The question is about if there is a way or not to reload its data without re-rendering the plugin which is causing it to "flicker" (because it disappears et reappears).

Comment: @gab No, you are replacing one instance of the plugin with another, which takes time. Facebook does not optimize for such use cases.

Answer (score 1):

Add an opacticy layer over the top of the facebook plugin div when a "page change" is needed.  Animate it to fully opaque. Call the FB.XFBML.parse() and give it a few moments to re-render.  Animate the layer to non-opaque, then remove the opacity layer from over the top of the facebook plugin div (or leave it there for the next time you need to do a "page change" without actually reloading the page.

This technique will give you a gracefully disappearing/reappearing plugin, rather than a jarringly harsh "flicker".

Answer (score 0):

Cache the Facebook likes of the **previous slide** + **current slide** + **next slide** on a slide change event. So that when you go to the next or previous one and its Facebook like should already be ready/loaded, the user should not see a flickering. Unless he/she goes to fast with the slides.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777907/many-facebook-like-buttons-on-one-page-with-different-thumbnails - This question/answer might relate to you...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this recently.

I got around it by wrapping the XFMBL in a variable... don't know why but without it it seemed to flicker...  a total hack of a way to stop the flickering but worked for me!!

```
      if(call == 0){
          FB.XFBML.parse();
          call = 1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

DMCS provided what seems to be the only half-proper answer, but it's butt ugly. You don't know how long it'll take on each persons web browser to render the stuff. The callback which supposedly says it's rendered doesn't work either. Also the flicker isn't seen in firefox but only in google chrome.